# What is the difference between JARs and packages?

Tags: java, jar, package

Is there any difference between a JAR file and a package?

Comment: may be you can extend your question? provide some context of your question?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A package is a way to **logically** organize your classes. For example, you can declare `package com.foo;` at the top of each source file that are related enough to reside in the `com.foo` package together. The Java compiler and runtime will also expect you to place such files in the path `com/foo/`, where the root of this path is a directory or JAR in your classpath.

A JAR file lets you **physically** organize your classes. You can take any Java files (and their parent directories, respecting the directory structure discussed above) and store them in a JAR file. A JAR file may contain files belonging to multiple packages, and multiple JAR files may contain files that belong to the same package. So, a JAR file is largely a way to store multiple class files in a single physical file.

There are some other special characteristics of JAR files. For example, you can specify a [`Main-Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) value in the JAR manifest to designate which class is the entry point for an application, and you can [seal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html) packages in a JAR file, "which means that all classes defined in that package must be archived in the same JAR file."

Comment: Note, normally you put class files into a jar, not Java files.  </nitpick>

Comment: Mandatory reason for packages in Java is to use them as name spaces, to allow two developers to name their class Hello, as long as they use different packages (or to have two classes Parser in the same application). Java provides rules to name packages (e.g. on top of DNS convention) and discourage to use default (unnamed) package to prevent class name collision.

Answer (score 6):

A package is a mechanism in Java for organizing classes into namespaces. A jar is a Java ARchive, a file that aggregates multiple Java classes into one.

Answer (score 3):

In brief, a JAR file is a physical file, structured much like a zip file,
that contains files used by your program at execution time. A jar will
typically include .class files, the executable versions of your classes, and
other resources like icons, pictures, language-specific properties files,
etc. The Java Tutorial describes jars, and how to create/manage them.
(http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jar/index.html)

Packages are defined like this in the Java Tutorial trail on interfaces and
packages: "A collection of related classes and interfaces providing access
protection and namespace management."
(http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutor...va/interpack/). While accurate, I
don't find that this definition, by itself, really gives you a good sense of
what a package is. For more information, go to the cited page and read
within that section of the tutorial.

Answer (score -3):

In classpath jar and package (directory) is same structures. Just jar more usefull for moving between computers than directory.

Comment: This is completely wrong.  A package is a directory structure within a classpath item, that classpath item can be a jar or directory, but the package is always a directory structure within the jar/directory.