# What is the relationship between package and jar file in java?

Tags: java, jar, package

What is the relationship between package and jar file in java? Do you get one jar file for each package?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138383/what-is-the-difference-between-jars-and-packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package consist of classes..

Jar : collection of packages and classes...

Answer (score 1):

A package logically organizes your classes. For example, you can declare package com.stackoverflow in each of the  source files to keep the all files in the same directory.

A JAR file lets you physically organize your classes. You can take any Java files and store them in a JAR file.
A JAR file may contain multiple packages, and multiple JAR files may contain files that belong to the same package. So, a JAR file is largely a way to store multiple class files in a single physical file.

Answer (score 0):

A package is a way of organizing Java types into groups of related types, and is part of the Java language. It doesn't exist as a resource or artifact, rather as a namespace, which means it's part of the type name.

A JAR is *not* part of the Java language but a file in a ZIP format. It contains loadable forms of Java types, i.e., class files, plus other files needed to deploy an application. Its purpose is to provide a deployment mechanism for Java code and resources.

It's like the difference between a chapter of a novel and a ZIP file containing a file representation of the novel. One is an abstraction, the other a file.